# Django, how to have multiple forms with one field default to the form name

Tags: django-forms

i have a list of company logos  in a grid system each linked to the same pop up form. with fields like name, email , phone ,region etc. i want each form to have a default field same as the name of the company logo , how can i do that????this is my code.

FORMS.PY

```
MARKETING_CHOICES = (('Yes', 'Yes'), ('No', 'No'))

class TechnologyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    number = forms.IntegerField()
    region = forms.CharField()
    email_marketing = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MARKETING_CHOICES)


class BoxuserForm(TechnologyForm):
    required_service_for = forms.CharField(max_length)
```

VIEWS.PY

```
class Technology_listView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'upload/technology_list.html'
    def post(self, request):
        form = AwsuserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            phone = form.cleaned_data.get('phone')
            region = form.cleaned_data.get('region')
            required_service_for = form.cleaned_data.get('required_service_for')
            email_marketing = form.cleaned_data.get('email_marketing')
            save.form()
```

Comment: required_service_for is the field which needs to have a default value for each form according to the logo clicked

Comment: If you populate the popup with a get request you can set any values in the view using initial. Alternatively you can add the value you want in some hidden container together with the logo, and use jquery to grab it and add it to the popup when you click the logo.